# google chrome extension messaging how many variables can be passed in a message?

Tags: google-chrome-extension, messaging

I am writing a Google Chrome extension.  The following request message works:

```
chrome.extension.sendRequest({cmd: "examineDetails", urlList: profileLink, photoList: photoType});
```

This request doesn't work:

```
chrome.extension.sendRequest({cmd: "openMessage", url: messageLink, keyWordList: keyWord, bGreeted: bAlreadyGreeted});
```

Is there a limit to the number of variables I can pass in a message or am I formatting this wrong?

Comment: Can you please also provide examples of what's inside those variables

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should work. Check your code and request listeners and try again.

Comment: what the dom inspector sees when i use the second statement is all but the last item "bGreeted".  if i reduce the number of arguments by removing the last item, "bGreeted" then doesn't see the new last argument "keyWordList."